# Create UIimage from three sf symbols next to each other

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I want to make a UIImage which is three UIImage(system:"star") next to each other, like *** where * is the star image. Any idea how I can do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw your image into a custom context 3 times.

```
func makeThreeStar() -> UIImage?  {
    guard let star = UIImage(systemName: "star") else { return nil }
    let size = CGSize(width: star.size.width * 3, height: star.size.height)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        for index in 0...2 {
            let point = CGPoint(x: star.size.width * CGFloat(index), y: 0)
            star.draw(at: point )
        }
    }
    return image
}
```